# How to query for matching values across multiple rows?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 tables: players and tags that join through player_tags. I want to get player Aaron only if it matches 1 or more tag names. In my case I want all players that have tag "test" and "new" but since they the property is across 2 rows I don't know how to do it.

```
table: players
ID    NAME
----- --------
1     AARON
2     JAMES


table: player_tags
ID    PLAYER_ID TAG_ID
----- --------- --------
1     1         1
2     1         2
3     2         1


table: tags
ID    NAME
----- --------
1     test
2     new
```

I created this query that of course does not work because tag 'test' and tag 'new' is in 2 different rows.

```
SELECT "players".name, "tags".name FROM "players"
  INNER JOIN "player_tags" ON "player_tags"."player_id" = "players"."id" 
  INNER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "player_tags"."tag_id"
WHERE
  "tags"."name" IS NOT NULL AND "tags"."name" = 'test' AND "tags"."name" = 'new'
```

I'm expecting to get player 1 as a response since it matches both tags. If I change 'AND' to 'OR' well I get both players but that is not what I want. I'm using postgres BTW.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select p.name as player_name, string_agg(t.name, ', ') as tags
from players p
  join player_tags pt ON pt.player_id = p.id 
  join tags t ON t.id = pt.tag_id
where t.name in ('new', 'test')
group by p.name
having count(t.id) > 1
```

The above implements the "*if it matches 1 or more tag names*" part so it returns those players that have *at least* one of those tags.

If you want only those players that have exactly those two tags, you can use:

```
select p.name as player_name, string_agg(t.name, ', ') as tags
from players p
  join player_tags pt ON pt.player_id = p.id 
  join tags t ON t.id = pt.tag_id
group by p.name
having array_agg(t.name order by t.name) = array['new', 'test']
```

Note that you need to specify the tag names in the array in alphabetical order.

Online example: http://rextester.com/NBKWU93227

Comment: Going to have crazy fun translating to ActiveRecord ORM if failed to even be able to create it with SQL

Comment: @code-gijoe: the joys of obfuscation layers.... the first query is pretty much standard SQL (except for the `string_agg`) - if your obfuscation layer can't deal with that, it really is broken.

Comment: For ActiveRecord this would be: Player.select("players.name, string_agg(tags.name, ', ')").joins(:tags).where(tags: {name: ['test', 'new']}).having("count(tags.id) > 1").group("players.name")

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with postgresql, but can you just join the player tags table once for each tag you're looking for?

In SQL Server, I could do something like:

```
select p.name
from players p 
join player_tags pt1 on p.id = pt1.player_id and pt1.tag_id = 1
join player_tags pt2 on pt1.player_id = pt2.player_id and pt2.tag_id = 2
```

Can you do something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You must ensure both conditions are true:

```
with ctag as
(
    select pt.player_id pid, t.name tname
    from players_tags pt 
         inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tag_id
    where tags.name in ('test','new')
)
select p.id, p.name
from players p
where exists (select 1 from ctag where pid = p.id and tname = 'test')
      and exists (selet 1 from ctag where pid = p.id and tname = 'new');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I haven't postgres  yet for test, tell me if there is some syntax errors.

in `ARRAY['test', 'new']` you can put desirable tag names.

```
select player, array_agg(tag) as tags from (
    SELECT players.name AS player, tags.name AS tag FROM players
    INNER JOIN player_tags
    ON players.ID = player_tags.PLAYER_ID 
    INNER JOIN tags
    ON player_tags.TAG_ID = tags.ID
) t
group by player
having
ARRAY(SELECT unnest(array_agg(tag)) ORDER BY 1)  = ARRAY(SELECT unnest(ARRAY['test', 'new']) ORDER BY 1)
```